# upgrade from django 1.4 to 1.7 - url tags error (I think!)

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-1.4, django-1.6, django-1.7

I am trying to upgrade my version of Django from 1.4.6 to 1.7, but I get the following error, which I have no idea how to solve:

My tracestack is as follows:

```
C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\project_name\project_name>python ../manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute     django.setup()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate app_config.ready()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\apps.py", line 15, in ready dt_settings.patch_all()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\settings.py", line 215, in patch_all  patch_root_urlconf()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\settings.py", line 203, in patch_root_urlconf reverse('djdt:render_panel')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 517, in reverse app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 329, in app_dict     self._populate()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 269, in _populate for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 367, in url_patterns     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\project_name\project_name\urls.py", line 10, in <module> url(r'', include('project_name.users.urls')),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 28, in include urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\project_name\project_name\users\urls.py", line 9, in <module> urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views', NameError: name 'patterns' is not defined
```

I am using python 2.7.

I have read the change docs and I have replaced all my url tags so that they are now displayed as: {% url "email_change" %} instead of {% url email_change %}

The final line of above errors is:

```
File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\project_name\project_name\users\urls.py", line 9, in <module> urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views', NameError: name 'patterns' is not defined
```

The code for this page from the users/urls.py file is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'', include('project_name.core.urls')),
                   url(r'', include('project_name.users.urls')),
                   url(r'', include('project_name.registration.urls')),
                   (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
                   # (r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
                   url(r'^contact_us/', 'contact.views.contact_us', name='contact_us'),
                   (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
                   )

# enable serving uploaded files in the DEBUG mode
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am assuming for the error message that the url tag is now incorrect under the new version of Django.
**Can anyone provide some help on how to solve this issue, b/c I am really stuck?**

** ***EDIT - added core urls.py file*** **

The following code is from my core/urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('project_name.core.views',

                   # ACHIEVEMENT DETAILS.
                   url(r'^resume_details/achievement_details/$',
                       'achievement_details',
                       name='achievement_details'),
                   url(r'^resume_details/achievement_details/add/$',
                       'achievement_details_add',
                       name='achievement_details_add'),
                   url(
                       r'^resume_details/achievement_details/delete/(?P<achievement_details_id>\d+)/$',
                       'achievement_details_delete',
                       name='achievement_details_delete'),
                   url(
                       r'^resume_details/achievement_details/duplicate/(?P<achievement_details_id>\d+)/$',
                       'achievement_details_duplicate',
                       name='achievement_details_duplicate'),
                   url(
                       r'^resume_details/achievement_details/edit/(?P<achievement_details_id>\d+)/$',
                       'achievement_details_edit',
                       name='achievement_details_edit'),

                   ....
```

Comment: Looks like you are showing your project-wide urls.py. Show your `project_name.users.urls` file contents.

Comment: alecxe - i have added the first section of my project_name/core/urls.py file. The project_name/users/urls.py is already displayed. Is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did solve this issue.

Instead of upgrading straight from Django 1.4 to 1.7, my advice is to handle your upgrades incrementally.

For example upgrade 1.4 to 1.5, then 1.6 to 1.6 and then 1.6 to 1.7. Make sure you test your project at each upgrade.

Handling the upgrades this way is much more manageable.

I hope that this helps somone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I recently wrote an article on how to upgrade from 1.4 to 1.7. Definitely learned a lot of things the hard way.
[labs.seedinvest.com/backend/upgrading-from-django-1-4-to-django-1-7/](http://labs.seedinvest.com/backend/upgrading-from-django-1-4-to-django-1-7/)

Comment: thanks for the article. i am sure someone else may find it useful.